# Whoosh ValueError: Keys must increase

Tags: python, whoosh

I'm getting the error

```
ValueError: Keys must increase: '\x00\x00\x0b\xc4\x00\x01' .. '\x00\x00\x0b\xc4\x00\x01'
```

at the line

```
writer.commit()
```

Where writer is an index.writer. I am adding 10K files to the index, and for performance, I commit every 100 files. This error only occurs at the 21st commit (20999 files).

The stack ends at add_all in whoosh...\filetables.py

Comment: That exception is raised only in the `OrderedHashWriter.add_all` method found in whoosh/filedb/filetables.py.  Perhaps you want to edit the source to print out more relevant information just before it raises the exception.  Or use a debugger.

Comment: Also read the traceback to see what method is calling `add_all` and work your way up the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try to run the source through a debugger, and see what I can find.